# How do you run a computation, that may fail, over a list of elements so that it terminates as soon as a failure is detected?

Tags: scala, scala-2.13

My computation that can fail is `halve()` below.  It returns `Left(errorMessage)` to indicate failure and `Right(value)` to indicate the successful halving of a number.

```
def halve(n: Int): Either[String, Int] =
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    Right(n / 2)
  } else {
    Left("cannot halve odd number")
  }
```

I'd like to apply the `halve` function to a list of `Int`s such that as soon as the first call to `halve` fails (e.g. when called with an odd number), the `halveAll` function immediately stops iterating over the numbers in `ns` and returns `Left(errorMessage)`.

Here is one way to achieve this:

```
def halveAll(ns: List[Int]): Either[String, List[Int]] =
  try {
    Right(
      for {
        n <- ns
        Right(halved) = halve(n)
      } yield n
    )
  } catch {
    case ex: MatchError =>
      Left("cannot match an odd number")
  }
```

I would prefer an approach that does **not** use exceptions.  Is there an idiomatic way of achieving this?  I'd prefer the approach to use only functionality in the Scala 2.x standard library.  If Cats or scalaz has an elegant solution, I'd be interested in hearing about it though.

Thank you!

Example usage of the `halveAll` function:

```
val allEven = List(2, 4, 6, 8)
val evenAndOdd = List(2, 4, 6, 7, 8)

println(halveAll(allEven))
println(halveAll(evenAndOdd))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked a dozen times but I am too lazy to search for a duplicate.

Have you ever heard the FP meme *"the answer is always `traverse`"*? Well, you are now part of that, since that is exactly the function you want.

Thus, if you have [**cats**](https://typelevel.org/cats/) in scope then you only need to do this:

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

def halveAll(ns: List[Int]): Either[String, List[Int]] =
  ns.traverse(halve)
```

If you don't have it already in scope, and don't want to add it just for a single function then you may use the `foldLeft` from Gaël J answer, or implement the recursion if you really want to stop iterating, like this:

```scala
def traverse[A, E, B](list: List[A])(f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, List[B]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], acc: List[B]): Either[E, List[B]] =
    remaining match {
      case a :: tail =>
        f(a) match {
          case Right(b) =>
            loop(remaining = tail, b :: acc)

          case Left(e) =>
            Left(e)
        }

      case Nil =>
        Right(acc.reverse)
    }

  loop(remaining = list, acc = List.empty)
}
```

---

> Disclaimer: What follows is only my opinion.

*I have heard the argument about not including **cats** for a single function many times, people simply don't realize is not just one function but probably many of them in the rest of the codebase; which ultimately means you are probably re-implementing many bits of the library in a worse way and with less testing*.

Answer (score 2):

The typical Scala approach (without libs) for this would be using `foldLeft` or a variant like this:

```scala
def halveAll(ns: List[Int]): Either[String, List[Int]] = {
  ns.foldLeft(Right(List.empty[Int])) { (acc, n) =>
    for { // for-comprehension on Either
      accVal <- acc
      x <- halve(n)
    } yield accVal :+ x
  }
}
```

As soon as a `Left` is produced by `halve`, it will continue iterating but will not call `halve` on the remaining items.

---

If you really need to not iterate anymore, you can use a recursive approach instead.

I guess it depends the size of the list but iterating over it should not be that costly most of the time.